# No users to select from the list in Azure Role assignments using Resource Group Owner

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

With an Azure Resource Group Owner I could not find any user from the list of users in Role assignments. I got a message "An error occurred. Please try again later." instead. Please see screenshot here. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFQfO.png)
The Resource Group Owner is a guest member. He is only owner of the resource group in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have restricted Guest access, they cannot enumerate users, i.e. they cannot get a user list from the AAD tenant.
The user might be able to find another user if they type in their full username in the search field.

Comment: I tried with both full username and email address of the user but nothing. Still same error.  The button Save is grayed out

Comment: Have you checked F12 tools in the browser, can you see an error in the Network tab there?

Comment: using F12 here is what errors I am seeing  : "fMde2SuDCDiV.js:10 [Microsoft_Azure_AD]  11:56:32 AM Users/ViewModels/SearchUtility 30001 SearchUtility: [ERROR][Code:30001][Source:Users/ViewModels/SearchUtility][Action:_handleErrorSearch][name:SearchUtility][Message:failed to fetch search results] Array(1)
r @ fMde2SuDCDiV.js:10
fMde2SuDCDiV.js:10 [Microsoft_Azure_AD]  11:57:46 AM Users/ViewModels/SearchUtility 30001 SearchUtility: [ERROR][Code:30001][Source:Users/ViewModels/SearchUtility][Action:_handleErrorSearch][name:SearchUtility][Message:failed to fetch search results] Array(1)"

Comment: Hmm that just kinda says that something went wrong. Can you see the network request for user search?

Comment: can you help me do this? I think I did not get how to do it myself

Comment: It is quite possible that this user will need additional access rights to be added in AAD. Otherwise they may not be able to use this portal UI.

Comment: I join your point of view. Thinking of least privilege principle,  do you have an idea what kind of role should attribute to him?

Comment: A minimum _could_ be to set their UserType to Member instead of Guest. This change would need to be done through Graph API/PowerShell as you can't do this from the portal. They will get the same privileges as a standard local user would, listing all users and groups etc.

Comment: thanks @juunas, it works indeed but I dont consider it as a good solution for my case as I will certainly forget about this change after a period. I have tested also another option "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/delegate-invitations#to-configure-external-collaboration-settings" however this one affects all guest accounts.